# How do I repair these cross-platform compatibility issues in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-platform

I'm using the following JavaScript below to alter what div appears on the page depending on the user's answer to the current question.

I know the code below is redundant and poorly written, but I need to use this specific code and simply make it compatible on an iPad. I am using the browser "iCabMobile" on the iPad and for some reason, the intended action does not happen at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioList_TextBox6_2_0').attr('checked')) {
        $("#first").show();
        $('#second').css('display', 'none');
    }
    if($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioList_TextBox6_2_1').attr('checked')) {
        $("#second").show();
        $('#first').css('display', 'none');
    }
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioList_TextBox6_2_0, #ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioList_TextBox6_2_1").change(function () {
        if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioList_TextBox6_2_0").attr("checked")) {
            $('#first').css('display', 'block');
            $('#second').css('display', 'none');
        }
        if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioList_TextBox6_2_1").attr("checked")) {
            $('#second').css('display', 'block');
            $('#first').css('display', 'none');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation (format it, paste it, highlight it, hit the code button).. that's very annoying on the eyes.

Comment: @RUJordan - way ahead of you ;)

Comment: depending your jquery version, you could have to use `.prop('checked')` instead of `attr()`. BTW, you should use `.hide()` instead of setting CSS property display

Comment: I'm totally with you Wolff, but I'm actually not able to alter the code itself. Just need to improve compatibility.